# Vertically and Horizontally Alignment of Text as well as UIImage inside a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uitextview, vertical-alignment

I am developing an application whereby I have a text as well as a `UIImage` inside a `UITextView` and I am trying to align both the text as well as the image vertically and to the left in the horizontal direction, how can I achieve this?

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Downward Arrow - 01.png") //Step (10) This is where the image is defined.

let attachment = NSTextAttachment() // Step (10) inserting a NSTextAttachment in order to attach the image in a UITextView.

let scaledImage = image?.scaleImageToSize(img: image!, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)) // this line of code is needed in order to resize the size of the image.

attachment.image = scaledImage // Step (10) setting the image to be attached to the scaled one that we just obtained out of the previous code.

//put your NSTextAttachment into and attributedString

let attString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment) // Step (10).

testTextView.textStorage.insert(attString, at: testTextView.selectedRange.location) // Step (10).
```

Comment: Are you using `UITextField` or `UITextView` ?

Comment: I am using a UITextView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have something like this using edge insets

```
let image = UIImage(named: "Downward Arrow - 01.png") //Step (10) This is where the image is defined.

let attachment = NSTextAttachment() // Step (10) inserting a NSTextAttachment in order to attach the image in a UITextView.

let scaledImage = image?.scaleImageToSize(img: image!, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)) // this line of code is needed in order to resize the size of the image.

let vCenter = ((testTextView.frame.size.height - 30) / 2)
let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: vCenter, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
testTextView.textContainerInset = padding

attachment.image = scaledImage // Step (10) setting the image to be attached to the scaled one that we just obtained out of the previous code.

//put your NSTextAttachment into and attributedString

let pic = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment) // Step (10).
let text = NSAttributedString(string: "YOUR TEXT")
let attString = NSMutableAttributedString()
attString.append(pic)
attString.append(text)

testTextView.textStorage.insert(attString, at: testTextView.selectedRange.location) // Step (10).
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks GIJOW for your swift reply that was very helpful in terms of solving my issue and aligning the UIImage inside the UITextView Vertically. However, what I am looking for is let's say that I have the following: let testText = "Hello, how are you" then my question is how can I add this text to the attached UIImage inside the UITextView and then align both vertically, at the same time aligning the text to the left and the image to the right? THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: sorry can't understand

Comment: let textInsideTextView = "Hello world"; let image = UIImage(named: "Downward Arrow - 01.png") //Step (10) This is where the image is defined.

let attachment = NSTextAttachment() // Step (10) inserting a NSTextAttachment in order to attach the image in a UITextView.

let scaledImage = image?.scaleImageToSize(img: image!, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)) // this line of code is needed in order to resize the size of the image.

attachment.image = scaledImage // Step (10) setting the image to be attached to the scaled one that we just obtained out of the previous code.

Comment: Now I need to create a variable that adds the text and image together before displaying them inside the UITextView? Basically, I want the text as well as the image to act as a placeholder inside the UITextView

Comment: indicativeDesignWorkingLifeTextView.textStorage.insert(attString, at: indicativeDesignWorkingLifeTextView.selectedRange.location) // Step (10).
   The above line of code is currently displaying only the image inside the UITextView I want the textInsideTextView to be displayed with the image inside the UITextView

Comment: I've edited my answer to try reach what you need but I doubt this is the best approach as UITextView has no placeholder, you have to create it manually, but if that fits for you I'm happy.

Comment: Excellent GIJOW you saved my life, that is exactly what I am looking for. One last thing and I will be really glad if you can help me with (1) how can I change the text font and color I added (i.e., text) (2) how can I align the image to the right while aligning the text to the left inside the UITextView? THANKS A LOT AND APOLOGIES FOR BOTHERING YOU.

Comment: for color you can use this: `let textAttributes = NSAttributedString (string: "YOUR TEXT", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.orange]); attString.append(textAttributes)` for alignments, I suggest you to learn a bit about attributedStrings. It helps can't do anything

Comment: Much appreciated GIJOW thanks a lot for your help :-)